# Joomla 3 provide admin access to a single component

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, acl

I created a user group with a corresponding user level in Joomla 3 to provide access to a sigle component (Akeeba subscriptions).

Then, in global configuration I gave the group the permission to login to admin. And in the component options to access admin interface and edit the component.

It works ok, but the user can't view the component dashboard. He can only see a basic report wiht the latest 20 subscriptions. He can't go beyond that.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I never used Akeeba Subs in particular, however I understand a bit how the Joomla ACL works.
Since the user is able to access the component in the backend, you made everything correct in the global permissions.
What the user can access and do within the component is specified in the extensions options. You will have to check the permissions tab there and enable the needed actions. Usually "Access Administration Interface" should give access to the dashboard of a component, but it's up to the component how it will handle it and what it will show.